# MS Office 2007 How can I track office's document changes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-office, office-interop

The Office 2007 interop API doesn't provide any event on document changes.

How can i get an event for each modification that happens ? (like OnDeleteSlide, OnAddSlide, etc..)

I think to get a hash of the document actually in ram, but don't see how...

Maybe check the state of the crtl+z control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word.Application.DocumentChange +=new ApplicationEvents2_DocumentChangeEventHandler(...);

Comment: As we know Excel Workbook consists of sheets. So you can determine all changes in sheet using `Excel.Application.SheetChange`. New sheet creation event - `Excel.Application.WorkbookNewSheet`. With MSPPt envistigate next : `pptApp.PresentationNewSlide`,`pptApp.NewPresentation` and `pptApp.WindowSelectionChange`